# Python azure-identity ClientSecretCredential

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I’m trying to get an access token via the azure-identity python package for accessing an Azure Service. I done the app registration in the Azure AD and I got the following C# code, which works as expected:

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string aasUrl)
{
    var tenantId = "<>";
    var appId = "<>";
    var appSecret = <>;
    string authorityUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

    // Config for OAuth client credentials 
    var clientCred = new ClientCredential(appId, appSecret);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(aasUrl, clientCred);

    //get access token
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

But when I try to redo the C# in python, I can’t get the get_token(scode:str) to work…I simply do not get what scope to pass into the get_token function.

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret, authority=authority)

token = credential.get_token(scope:str) #scope?
```

When I use the .net Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory library I don’t have to think about scope.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Yup! Got it to work thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I use the .net Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory library I don’t have to think about scope.

Actually, you have thought about it. When you use the code below via .net sdk, there is an `aasUrl`, this is the equivalent you need to specify in python sdk.

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(aasUrl, clientCred);
```

With `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`, the method `AcquireTokenAsync` essentially uses the [Azure AD client credential flow v1.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, so this parameter is named as [`resource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret), i.e. the `resource` parameter in this method [`AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientCredential)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ClientCredential_).

In python sdk `azure.identity`, this method `get_token` essentially uses [Azure AD client credential flow v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, when v1.0 endpoint migrates to v2.0, there are some changes, one of them is the `resource`, it changed to [`scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources). When using `scope`, you need to specify the permission you want to access, you can also use [`/.default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope), then by default all the permissions added to the app will be requested.

So in your case, you just need to use the `scope` as `aasUrl/.default`, e.g. `https://management.azure.com/.default`, it depends on yourself.

```
token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")
```

Also have a test with the code on my side, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind if you want to use the token in a request, you have to use `token.token`, for example `requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token.token}"})`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Graph API you could use as

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

https://graph.microsoft.com/Directory.Read

https://graph.microsoft.com/user_impersonation
```

if you are using Azure Resource Manager API then the base uri would be https://management.core.windows.net followed by the necessary permission.

If you want to acquire a token for all the static scopes of a v1.0 application, append ".default" to the app ID URI of the API

You Will see the APP Id uri in the Application Overview page

[image]

if you have not created app id uri, you set the uri and add permission scope

Answer (score 0):

I am using azure-identity 1.6.1 and Python 3.7 version and I had to make couple of more changes to the solution mentioned above by @Joy Wang-MSFT

for retrieving the token, I had to use just .default

```
token = clientcredential.get_token(".default")
```

But one issue with this one was the token retreived did not come out with the roles.

So finally using the client_id/app_id , worked for me and the token had roles as well

```
token = clientcredential.get_token("{client_id}/.default")
```