# Azure Identity client library for Python picks up the wrong tenant ID

Tags: python, azure, azure-identity

I'm using [Azure Identity client library for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python) to authenticate a local server for testing. It works well for the people that has no private **tenantID** under **managedByTenants** because the identity library would pick the homeTenantID for authentication.

For my case, since I have a private **tenantID**, the identity library picked this one and treated as the homeTenantId. As a result, I cannot stop running my local server, because I got the error tells me that the tenantID is wrong. How can I remove this private tenantID?

INFO:

After checking my Azure login account details by **az account show** I found I have 2 tenant ID shown as follow

```
"environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "homeTenantId": "132n1938-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx", (our department tenant ID)
  "id": "cynk120n-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
  "isDefault": true,
"managedByTenants": [
    {
      "tenantId": "1n2b7651-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" (Where this comes from? And how can I remove it?)
    }
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

*To remove the Private tenant from your managed tenantID you should be login from `Managed tenant` and also you should have the privilege to delete the child tenant from Managed tenant.*

> To remove a tenant from your Partner Center account, find its name on
> the Tenants page (in Account settings), then select Remove. You'll be
> prompted to confirm that you want to remove the tenant. After you do
> so, no users in that tenant will be able to sign into the Partner
> Center account, and any permissions you have configured for those
> users will be removed.

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION| Remove a tenant***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/manage-tenants)
- [***MS Q&A discussion***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/123205/access-token-has-the-wrong-tenantid.html) which is suggested by @*amanpreetsingh-msft* for the similar issue.
- [***SO THREAD| Python azure-identity ClientSecretCredential***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398527/python-azure-identity-clientsecretcredential)